# Rotation of marker over google map with animation like Uber or Ola in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation, react-native-maps

I am working on a project similar to UBER or OLA. I have used [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) library for that. I have used React Native geolocation to fetch the current location. I have also taken a reference to this [react-native-maps example](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/AnimatedMarkers.js). but the rotation of the marker is not working. can anyone help? where am I wrong?

**And This code works well in Android, But not in iOS**

Thanks in advance.

Below I share my code

```
render(){
     return(
           <MapView
              ref={component => (this.map = component)}
              provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
              style={styles.mapStyle}
            >

              <Marker. Animated
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: this.state.currentLocation.latitude,
                  longitude: this.state.currentLocation.longitude
                }}
                ref={marker => {
                  this.marker = marker;
                }}
                flat
                style={{
                  transform: [
                    {
                      rotate:
                        this.state.currentLocation.heading === 
                   undefined
                          ? "0deg"
                          : `${this.state.currentLocation.heading}deg`
                    }
                  ]
                }}
                image={"rickshaw"}
              />
)}
```

And I have updated marker location in **componentDidUpdate**

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.currentLocation !== this.state.currentLocation) {
      let newCoordinate = this.state.currentLocation;
      let previousLocation = prevState.currentLocation;
      if (utility.getOS() === "android") {
        console.log("update marker");
        if (this.marker) {
          this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
            this.state.currentLocation,
            1000
          );
        }
      } else {
        if (newCoordinate !== null && previousLocation !== null) {
          const oldCoordinate = new AnimatedRegion({
            latitude: previousLocation.latitude,
            longitude: previousLocation.longitude
          });
          oldCoordinate.timing(newCoordinate).start();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: In Uber the marker stay in center while moving map.

Comment: Thanks, But  I am concern about the rotation/angle of marker (car)

Comment: well, I would suggest you to use custom marker view, I think that will be more reliable way for rotation and other things

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Hey, thanks for your reply. I have tried your suggestion but I have found one another issue. I am getting heading always -1 in iOS in react native geolocation response. do you have any idea?